how to decompress the DEFLATE compressed data
I wanted to create the internet trend BadApple in c++ console. By extracting every frame from the BadApple video using ffmpeg in .png format and reading RGB pixel data from it. I already have a boiler plate code on how to extract chunks by reading this article in Wikipedia. And I don't want to use any libraries.
I found many sources on how DEFLATE compression works and all the FILTER methods, but can't find sources for how to undo the FILTER methods and others.
Please Help.
Note: Some might suggest to use an easy extension like .bmp where we can ready the pixel data directly without any decompression, which I already did and completed the project. Here's the link. But I really want to learn how the algorithm works. Thanks

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h has fairly easy to read code to parse PNG files.

You can always refer to the RFC as well. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2083

It's all in the PNG specification.


